# Kicad 6: output vs power output

Tags: kicad

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Input Power pin not driven by any Output Power pin
```

This is the component failing
[image]

This is my power supply. A RA0505
[image]

And this is the PowerSupply Schematic:
[image]

What is the right way of fixing this? Should GND be Output or Power Output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KiCad checks if there are any power pin conflicts (i.e. two `power outputs` on one net) and if all power inputs are in the same net as a power output. That means that you should have one power output ground pin (probably on the pin you are highlighting, indeed) or on a connector that delivers power.

In case you do not have a power out component (or there is a switch or jumper in between), you can always choose to add a power flag to denote explicitly that a net has the power output constraint fulfilled.

Lastly, if you do not care about DRC, you could make problematic pins passive. That dismisses the warning.

Edit: Your `+Vout` should probably be a power output as well, if you want to do everything according to convention. However, since there is a jumper next to it, it probably doesn't really matter, and you should use a power flag on the right of the jumper.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Error: Input Power pin not driven by any Output Power pin
> ```

If you go to "place power port" and select "power flag" and attach it to the node in question, it will rectify this. It's a bit of a bodgy way that KiCAD does this but, who am I to argue.

[image]